# make the function that works as filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am newbie of AngularJS. I tried to make the function that works as filter:

**index.html**

```
    <ul class="phones">
      <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:isLong">
        {{phone.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**controllers.js**

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];

  $scope.islong = function(phone) {
    var n = phone.name.length;
    if ( n > 7) { return true } else { return false };
  }
});
```

**JsBin**

http://jsbin.com/huwam/1/edit

But this doesn't work... Please help me. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to reference the function, not call it:

```
 <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:isLong">
```

The function itself gets a single item as argument:

```
$scope.isLong = function(phone) {
```

Comment: I tried that the rest of function is `var n = phone.name.length; if ( n > 7) { return true } else { return false };`, but this doesn't work. I read the API document and found that the filter objective can be function, so I want to try this way. Please tell me where is wrong.

Comment: @weed it works for me. But I had a typo. In case you copied it: it has to be `$scope.isLong = function(phone) {`

Comment: In my machine, It doesn't still work. Thank you a lot for help!

Comment: @weed You still have the typo in your JSBin

Answer (score 3):

As @zeroflagL said,

"You only need to reference the function, not call it:"

```
 <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:isLong">
```

Another approach would create a custom filter to achieve this aim.

The main reason is: Custom filters are reusable at any scope.

**html**

```
<ul class="phones">
  <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | islong">
    {{phone.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**javascript**

```
phonecatApp.filter("islong", function() {
    return function(items) {
       return items.filter(function(item) { return item.name.length > 7});
    };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/F374dQ?p=preview

May be you want add parameters:

**html**

```
<ul class="phones">
  <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | islong:7">
    {{phone.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**javascript**

```
phonecatApp.filter("islong", function() {
    return function(items, length) {
       return items.filter(function(item) { return item.name.length > length});
    };
});
```

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: Perfect and recommended solution.

Comment: A filter takes an input and creates an output based on the input. The input of `myFilter` is `phones`, which is an array. `myFilter` neither expects nor returns an array, which is necessary for `ng-repeat`.